# Three.js using raycast from camera to select items

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hey guys so I'm trying to get a ray to go straight out from the camera intersect with whatever i'm looking at but all the references i've seen use the mouse and I cant figure out how to convert.

code I have so far:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

function render() 
{ 
    raycaster.set(camera, 0);

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I did something similar, just with the mouse position instead of the camera.

```
var x = (event.offsetX / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
var y = -(event.offsetY / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;
var z = 0.5;
var mousePosition = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

mousePosition.unproject(camera);
raycaster.set(camera.position, mousePosition.sub(camera.position).normalize());

var intersectObjects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

if (intersectObjects.length) {
    // do something
}
```

> You could try to replace the first two lines, `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` with the center of your canvas like:

```
var x = ((canvasElement.clientWidth / 2) / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
var y = -((canvasElement.clientHeight / 2) / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;
```

> EDIT: Now you could do something special with the intersect cube. For example, show his wireframes like: `intersectObjects[0].material.wireframe = true`.
>
> NOTE: The `intersectObjects`-array is sorted by the distance. So the nearest object will be at index 0.

.

> EDIT #2: You could create an "update loop" (`update()` function) to use the above code. I know two ways to do that:

- use `setInterval(update, 1000 / 60)`: `1000 / 60` to make it call 60 times per second. Negative: it will be imprecise when the execution of the `update` function will take more time than 16.6 (1000 / 60) milliseconds
- call the `update`-method in your `render` method. Positive: it will be (more) precise and you have seperated your application- from the render-logic!

  function update() {
      // put above code here
  }

  function render() { 
      // ...
      update();
  }

Comment: Thank you!  Would you place all of this in the render?

Comment: No, you shouldn't put it into the `render` function! It has nothing to do with the render-logic!

Comment: sorry all the other stuf I saw went into the render.  I think its working now I just need to test it

Comment: Okay for some reason the ray is always selecting three objects I guess but no matter how I move the camera it doesn't seem to change.  only thing I changed was this:                                                                                                   `for ( var i = 0; i < intersectObjects.length; i++ ) {

    intersectObjects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
        console.log(intersectObjects);
    }`

Comment: in my above code the `update`-method will be call in the `render`-method, so it went to the render logic. What i meant is, that you should seperate the update logic from the render logic for cleaner code. what exactly do you want to do with the intersect objects?

Comment: I need to be able to tell what the camera is looking at so I can select it.

Comment: So, I don't understand your problem. `intersectObjects` should contain the objects who the camera is looking at. If the camera always look at the scene, `camera.lookAt(scene.position)`, then it isn't unusual that the ray will always select three objects. -> The code you have so far shouldn't be the problem?!